# How can i acces protected members in a derived class from a base class that is firend of another class

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement a deque that is derived from another class queue which is friend of a class named Node. In the class node i have info and *next set as private and as public the set and get functions.

In the queue class i have a pointer prim which points to the first node and an ultim pointer which points to the last node(both are protected) + the set and get functions.
The problem comes when i try to use setPrim in the derived class. I get a compiler error 'class node' has no member named 'setPrim'.

Why does this occur and how can i fix it?

```
class node
{
protected:
    char info;
    node *next;
public:
    node()
    {
        next=NULL;
    }
    ~node()
    {
    }
    char getInfo()
    {
        return info;
    }
    node* getNext()
    {
        return next;
    }
    void setInfo(char x)
    {
        info=x;
    }
    void setNext(node* x)
    {
        next=x;
    }
    friend class Queue;
    };
class Queue
    {
    protected:
    node *prim;
    node *ultim;
public:
    char aux;
    int dim_max;
    Queue(int maximuml)
    {
        prim=NULL;
        ultim=NULL;
        dim_max=maxim;
    }
    virtual ~Queue()
    {
        delete []prim;
        delete []ultim;
    }
    node* getPrim()
    {
        return prim;
    }
    node* setPrim(node *x)
    {
        prim=x;
    }
    node* getUltim()
    {
        return ultim;
    }
    node* setUltim(node *x)
    {
        ultim=x;
    }
    void print()
    {}
    virtual void push(char x)
    {}
    virtual void pop()
    {}
}
class Deque: public Queue
{
public:
    Deque(int maximum,int maxi):Queue(maximum)
    {
        ___prim->setPrim();___
        ultim=NULL;
        dim_max=maxi;
        cnt=0;
    }
    ~Deque()
    {
       delete []prim;
       delete []ultim;
    }
    void push(char x,int ok)
    {}
    void pop(int ok)
    {}
};
```

Comment: Just a side note... There is absolutely no point for `getInfo`, `setInfo`, `getNext`, and `setNext` to exist. They just bloat the code. Same for the simple getters/setters in the other classes.

Comment: I am pretty sure you cann narrow that down to a [mcve] as required here.

Comment: the compiler error does occur because 'class node' has no member named 'setPrim'. Queue class has that method, which you can call either `this->setPrim()` or just `setPrim()`. Also, you should not have that `~Deque` destructor, as these members are already deleted in base class `Queue` destructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`prim` is of type `node`. Then you do:

```
prim->setPrim();
```

But the `node` class does not have a function called `setPrim()`. It's the `Queue` class that has a `setPrim()` function, not `node`. Did you mean to instead do this?

```
setPrim(prim);
```

Also, although unrelated to your question, your `Deque` destructor deletes `prim` and `ultim` which will be deleted again by the `Queue` destructor. Do not delete the same object more than once. Also, `delete[]` should only be used for things that were allocated using `new []`.

Comment: I seem to have misunderstood the question from the title, this answers it. I would add a comment about the double deletes going on

Comment: @A.H. Yep. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understood what i did wrong. i actually ment setPrim(NULL);

Answer (score 0):

In C++ friendship is not inherited. From the [standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.friend#10)

> Friendship is neither inherited nor transitive.

```
class A {
  friend class B;
  int a;
};

class B {
  friend class C;
};

class C  {
  void f(A* p) {
    p->a++;         // error: C is not a friend of A despite being a friend of a friend
  }
};

class D : public B  {
  void f(A* p) {
    p->a++;         // error: D is not a friend of A despite being derived from a friend
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually in my mobile but if my "mind compiler" works fine you can use CRTP (Curiously Recursively Template Pattern). Try something like the following code:

```
template<typename Derived>
class Base : public Derived {
     void print() {
          return reinterpret_cast<Derived>(this).print();
     }
};
class foo : public Base<foo> {
      void print() {
          std::cout<<"Hello from foo";
      }
};
```

I hope that it can be useful for you